# JavaScript / jQuery: how to split string with multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split, substring

I have a string that always contains 8 variable values that are separated with a hypen (-) like in the following example:

5-2-2-2-2-2-2-1

What is the best way to split this into 8 separate values so that I can use each of them in a variable if the values can be either an integer or the value 'n/a' ?

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var str = '5-2-2-2-2-2-2-1';
 var parts = str.split('-');
 for (var i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
    console.log(parts[i]);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! I am pretty new to JS so sorry if this is a simple question but how do I get the values assigned to variables in this case ? Will the for loop just create variables with i as their name, like var1, var2 etc. ? I would need my variables be called ms1, ms2 etc.

Comment: `parts[0]` contains `5`, `parts[1]` contains `2`, `parts[2]` contains `2` etc. `str.split()` will produce an array. so `parts` is an array. read more about javascript arrays

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for the [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method